# Two-egg problem - just the ideal height for k eggs

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

The solutions listed on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Egg_dropping_puzzle) and other websites to the egg dropping puzzle calculate the maximum amount of drops, or the worse case scenario until we reach the critical floor where the egg breaks. But what if I want an algorithm that *only* returns the **ideal floor to start from?**

For example: 1 egg, 100 foors = 1:
Obvious because you need to check every floor until it breaks.

2 eggs, 100 floors = 14:
We start at floor k. If it breaks, we just need to check k-1 steps beforehand as it's a 1-egg problem.
If it doesn't break, we move k-1 steps, so that the maximum amount of steps still remains k. This leads to k + k -1 + k-2... = k(k+1) / 2  >=  100, k = ~14 rounded up.

How do I find the general best floor for e eggs and n floors?

Comment: Anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that the dynamic programming data structure has the answer encoded in it.  Namely that you figure out how many drops are needed, and then it is the maximum floors with 1 less drop and 1 less egg plus 1 (the test egg which, if it breaks, puts you in the previously solved solution.)

Here is a Python solution with generators that is slightly inefficient but demonstrates the ideas in a hopefully clear manner.

```
def floors_by_drops (eggs):
    drops = 0
    if eggs == 1:
        while True:
            drops = drops + 1
            yield (drops, drops)
    else:
        floors = 1
        drops = 1
        yield (drops, floors)
        prev_floors = floors_by_drops(eggs-1)
        while True:
            drops = drops + 1
            (this_drops, this_floors) = prev_floors.next()
            if drops <= this_drops:
                # We are not able to use the last egg in our best strategy.
                yield (drops, this_floors)
                floors = this_floors
            else:
                # We drop an egg at this_floors+1
                # If we fail, we can do this_floors with 1 less egg and one less drop.
                # If we succeed, we can do floors with all eggs and one less drop.
                floors = floors + this_floors + 1
                yield (drops, floors)

def first_floor (eggs, floors):
    if eggs == 1:
        return 1 # always
    else:
        prev_eggs_iterator = floors_by_drops(eggs-1)
        eggs_iterator = floors_by_drops(eggs)
        prev_floors = 0
        while True:
            # eggs_iterator is always 1 more drop than prev_eggs_iterator
            this_floors = eggs_iterator.next()[1]
            if floors <= this_floors:
                return prev_floors + 1
            prev_floors = prev_eggs_iterator.next()[1]

print(first_floor(2, 100))
```